# How do I display the resuls of my ajax DB query?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am querying my DB with some query which returns 2 fields. I'm just wondering what's the better/best way of displaying the search results.

in the old days, I would have been using string concatenation.

example:

```
var html="";
$.each(data, function () {
    var html = html + "<div><span>" + this.field1 + "</span><br /><span>" + this.field2 + "</span><br /></div>";
});
```

I'm hoping things would've have improved and something better like jquery can be used? I did search the net but can't find anything useful.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your code doesn't work at all. The `var` declaration inside the function is creating a new local variable, so you're not updating the outer variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String concatenation is still quite popular. But with jQuery you can create elements using object syntax:

```
$.each(data, function() {
    var field1 = $("<span>", { text: this.field1 });
    var field2 = $("<span>", { text: this.field2 });
    $("<div>").append(field1, "<br>", field2).appendTo("#results");
});
```

However, it's quite possible that this will be slower than the concatenation version. This makes lots of calls to DOM functions to create elements and append them to the DOM, one at a time. String concatenation, on the other hand, is relatively efficient. If you do all the concatenation, and then finally do `$("#results").html(html)` at the end, it will make use of the browser's internal HTML parser to construct all the elements in one fell swoop. This is optimized very heavily in all browsers.

Comment: +1 For the interesting explanation on object syntax versus concatenation in combination with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the append function in JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var div = $("<div></div>");
   var span1 = $("<span></span>");
   span1.append("value 1");
   var span2 = $("<span></span>");
   span2.append("value 2");
   div.append(span1).append("<br>").append(span2).append("<br>");
   $("body").append(div);
});
```

Replace the text values with the values you are returning from your query.

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imoshtokill/g97owc5y/)